# ¿Como crear un subdominio en AWS EC2 para una api rest?

Tags: nodejs, api, express, aws

Tengo comprado el dominio en **GoDaddy**, controlado por **Cloudflare**

A parte tengo el servidor en **AWS** vinculado a Cloudflare, la idea que tengo es crear un subdominio para la **API** *(Express)*
p.e. `api.midomino.com` otro para el **panel** administrativo p.e. `panel.midominio.com`

dejando `www.midominio.com` para la parte **pública**.

Tanto `www.midominio.com` como `panel.midominio.com` se alimentarían de la misma api *(api.midominio.com)*.

He probado con Route53 y Elastic IP, pero nunca he trabajado con AWS más allá de crear una instancia e instalar MEAN y me pierdo un poco.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

En el panel de control de GoDaddy puedes cambiar los DNS a los que apunta tu dominio. Con Route53 eres capaz de crear end points para tus dominios, indicando si quieres apuntarlo hacia un Bucket S3 (uno para tu API y otro para tu sitio web publico), u otro recurso web (certificados de seguridad de CloudFare).

Te recomiendo chequear esta [referencia](https://medium.com/@brodartec/hosting-a-static-site-with-https-enabled-using-aws-s3-cloudfront-and-godaddy-826dae41fdc6)